# Magento 2.4.2: Is it required to keep the cronjob "magento_newrelicreporting_cron" running?

Tags: magento2.4

Please let me know if it is required to keep the cronjob "magento_newrelicreporting_cron" running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you use New Relic for reporting

Comment: Where can I disable New Relic?

Comment: bin/magento module:disable Magento_NewRelicReporting